# Accessing Iterator After Deletion Causes Crash

Tags: c++, pointers, crash, iterator

so I'm used to coding in C# and have just started using C++ again after a pretty substantial break. Essentially what I'm trying to do is to create a program that has lists of students with IDs, in courses.

I have this code that essentially prints out all available students in courses.

```
auto allCourses = WSUCourse::getAllCourses();
   std::for_each(
       allCourses.begin(),
       allCourses.end(),
       GetCoursePrinter());
```

The `GetCoursePrinter()` is called in this code in the constructor

```
struct GetCoursePrinter
{
   void operator () (
      MyCourse *coursePtr
   )
   {
      std::cout << coursePtr->getIdentifier() <<
         ": " <<
         coursePtr->getTitle() <<
         std::endl;
   }
};
```

My problem is after I delete an enrollment like so

```
MyEnrollment *enrollmentPtr = MyEnrollment::findEnrollment(
   MyStudent::getStudentWithUniqueID(1000002),
   MyCourse::getCourseWithIdentifier("CS 2800")
);
delete enrollmentPtr;
```

And then try to print it with GetCoursePrinter it crashes. I believe this is because it's trying to access something that doesn't exist. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to call something like this

```
if (allCourses.current() != null)
{
    GetCoursePrinter();
}
else
{
    //do nothing
}
```

Comment: Given that you are new to C++, do you *really* need to store pointers in `allCourses`? There are situations where you need to, but these are few and far between, and storing pointers brings in extra complexity, as you have found out. So, store objects if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call:

```
delete enrollmentPtr;
```

you need to remove this item in environment.